# Truffle Test: How to Run n times the same function

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

Since I have to study the variation of the gasUsed of a function, using Truffle Test is it possible to do a test that runs n times the same function without going out of gas or exceding the block gas limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unless you configure your TestRPC/Ganache otherwise (auto-mining every X seconds), there will only be one transaction per block, so blockgas limit should not be the problem.
2. To check the variations of used gas, you can do something like this (pseudocode):

arrayWithParameters[];

```
for (i=0; i<arrayWithParameters[].length; i++) {

let transaction = await yourContract.function(arrayWithParameters[i]);

checkGasOf(transaction);

}
```